# Theorem 3.3 Apostol's Analytic Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The below texts are from the book Introduction to Analytic Number Theory by Apostol:

[image]

Note. Part (d) Thm 3.2 [green-underlined] is $$\sum_{n\le x}n^a=\dfrac{x^{a+1}}{a+1} +O(x^a) \ \ \text{if} \ a\ge0.$$

I don't understand the-red-underlined-equation. My questions are:

1- Summation in the equation of part (d)of Thm 3.2 is over *all* of $n\le x$ i.e. $1, 2,  \dots, [x] $. But, in the red-underlined eq. summation (for fixed $d$) is not over all of the positive integers less than $\frac{x}{d}$; i.e. only over those are the lattice points. So why use of a wrong equation?

2- Even with an intuitive way of thought, the-red-underlined-equation does not make sense: If $O(1)$ means some constant for any $x$ and any $d$ so the number of lattice points is fully determined by $x$ for fixed $d$; and, if the 'constant' $O(1)$ varies with the choice of $x$ and $d$, so the equation doesn't say anything at all, said differently, the number of positive integers between $1$ and $\frac{x}{d}$ carrying some characteristic [def. of $q$] is $\frac{x}{d} - \text{some number}$, (trivial statement!).

I believe these two questions are different and I would truly appreciate simple clear explanations.

Edit. Figure 3.1 is added below.

[image]

Comment: See $\sum_{n \leq x} 1 = \lfloor x \rfloor = x - \{x\}$ where $\{x\}$= fractional part of $x$. And $\{x\} < 1$, so we can write as $O(1)$. This is what he is using.

Comment: @S.C., NO! as I wrote in the first question and also according to the text, O(1) is not {x} because not all the q's between 1 and x/d enter in the summation.

Comment: See if $f(x) = \{x\}$ then there is no harm in saying $f(x)$ is $ O(1)$. It's just bounding. We don't need to be precise here.

Comment: @S.C., $\sum_{q\le x/d} 1$ is not correct because it means sum over all positive integers $\le x/d$; i.e. different from the statement of the book, which says "sum over *certain* lattice points" .

Comment: @S.C., in other words, not all the q's $1, \dots, [x/d]$ are lattice points. - I added figure. For example, number of lattice points for x=10 and d=1 is not 10, it's 3.

Comment: You want to count lattice points, i.e. pairs $(q,d)$ such that $qd \leq x$.  OK - let $d$ vary from 1 to the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.  How many $q$'s are possible?  Well, you need $q \leq x/d$.  So you *are* summing over every $q$ between 1 and $x/d$.

Comment: @JohnM But, for example, number of lattice points for x=10 and d=1 is not 10, it's 1; as the figure shows.

Comment: @Liebe It is not supposed to be counting lattice points for $qd=10$.  You are counting lattice points for which $qd \leq 10$.  The figure is only showing you $qd = 1, 4, 10$.  But you also need to count $qd = 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$ as well.

Comment: @JohnM Thank you. I understood it!